# Uploadify - how to determine what fileExt option was selected?

Tags: javascript, uploadify

I'm looking at http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/fileext/ and  http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onselect/ and I'm wondering, if there is any way to determine which file filter option was selected by user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this problem usng simple `option list` and dynamically change the possible filter inside that control